# java PaaS performance

Tags: java, java-ee-7, paas, jelastic

my java ee 7 app requires a lot of CPU resources. I test it on Jelastic with 64 cloudlets. During the test, the app consumed up to 60 cloudlets. But at end of the test, I was surprised to see that the app runs at least 2-3 time faster on my macbook pro (i7, dual core) vs 60 Jelastic cloudlet.
Is it normal that 60 Jelastic cloudlets are less performant than a laptop?

The app doesn't call any external resources.

Could you please recommend a very performant and user friendly PaaS

Thanks
Khalil

Answer (score 0):

Try Amazon AWS, the performance is according to the hardware you rent. And don't underestimate using your own hardware, if you can afford it.

Comment: Not really. An Infoworld test found performance of "same spec" Amazon instances can vary by up to 10x (see http://www.infoworld.com/sites/infoworld.com/files/pdfe/amazon_t1micro_results.pdf). Also of course AWS is just IaaS whilst Khalil is looking for PaaS.